# Kerberos - SPN and keytabs

Tags: kerberos, spnego, spn

I have a project that have embedded jetty with SPNEGO enabled. I would like to be able to run this project locally for development purposes (WITH SPNEGO enabled!)

My question is, is the SPN and keytab associated with a particular server at all or can I use the same set on multiple instances of my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerberos requires that both the client and server somehow figure the service principal to use without any prior contact. If you have control of both the client and server, you can use any principal you want provided you configure both sides to 
use the same principal.

In the `SPNEGO` case, the client does the "standard" thing and builds a principal based on the hostname of the server. (i.e. I want to talk to `www.foo.com`, I'll try 
requesting an `HTTP/www.foo.com` service ticket and see if the server accepts it. )

I don't know of any way to get the `SPNEGO` code in the browser to use a fixed service principal. So in this case you'll need a separate keytab for each server.