# Service mapping for keytabs

Tags: authentication, kerberos

Say I have a HTTP server that has instances running on machines `virt01` through `virt09` which have CNAMEs `svc01` through `svc09`. I want to add Kerberos auth to it.

Assume:

- I'm on AD domain `example.com`
- My host DNS entries are `host@example.com`
- My Kerberos realm is `EXAMPLE.COM`,

From answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22991646/3821009) one, I figured that the keytab has to contain entries such as:

```
HTTP/virt01.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
...
HTTP/virt09.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
HTTP/svc01.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
...
HTTP/svc09.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

in order for browsers and other clients (such as other non-interactive services) to be able to authenticate against the servers. Is the above correct?

If it is, a follow up question is - is there a way to make a "service alias" so to speak, so I can put just one entry in keytab:

```
HTTP/svc-alias.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

somehow? This in order to be able to move the service to other hosts for example and not have to regen the keytab with a new host and CNAME added. Especially important for local testing. E.g. if this is tested on `workstation583`, a new keytab entry for that workstation would have to be made, which is really inconvenient.

If not possible, what is the easiest way to manage adding / removing hostnames? How is this done in practice with multi-server deployments to make it manageable?

Any resources answering any of the above are appreciated as well.

Comment: A keytab is implementation-dependent as to how it picks which keys to use. However, this won't help you because the client is always going to resolve the authoritative record of the host to look up an SPN. Aliases are explicitly not recommended for Kerberos for security reasons.

Comment: @Steve Thanks! "Aliases are explicitly not recommended for Kerberos for security reasons." Why is that? Any references so I read more about that?

Comment: The RFC itself is clear on this, section 1.3 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4120

Comment: @Steve If you meant this part "hus, for example, one should not rely
   on an unprotected DNS record to map a host alias to the primary name
   of a server...", then I think that's not the same I'm asking for. I'm asking for a KDC to do the principal aliasing internally only. I.e. if clients asks for principal `svc01`, then have the KDC return the key for `svc-alias`, where `svc-alias` is in server's keytab. That way client can ask for  any `svcXX` and get the ticket that the server can decode. Otherwise, server would need all `svcXX` principals in its keytab, which I'm not sure how to scale

Comment: Oh I see. You should just be able to add the names as SPNs to the service account in AD. You can't use an alias though for the above reason. You have to use an A record name, which if it's the dev workstation might be problematic if it's already joined to the domain.

Comment: If you have a Load Balancer whose canonical DNS name is `svc-alias.example.com`, if you define a SPN for that Load Balancer, and if your web services accept service tickets using that "generic" SPN... it would work. That's how some Hadoop components manage High Availability. But web servers don't do that by default... Also, you need the LB to manage "sticky" connections because SPNego itself requires a round-trip (with _"401 require Kerberos or NTLM token" challenge)_ before starting kerberos auth proper.